# NodeJS digital Signature using Cryptography

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature

> What I am trying to do:

Trying to create an internal system where users upload **PDF** files and send them to other users.

These PDF files should be **signed using Digital Signature**.

> What I have done and searched for:

I have found this npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-signpdf which I think do exactly what I want.

> Problem is:

This package requires **p12 certificate** and I don't know if it possible to create this certificate for each user on the system to identify them.

And if it is possible then how I do it?

And if it is not, what is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create p12 certificate for each user, but bear in mind that their cert is not recognized due to the chain of trust problem. You still can sign it 
 using your own created cert but with warning only.

You have to get the digital cert from Certificate Authority which is not cheap if you have to buy each cert for each of your users.

Comment: So the best solution is to create only one certificate on my server and sign each pdf and very it?

Comment: I guess this is the only solution.